# understanding ternary operator in jquery `show` and `hide` method.

Tags: jquery

Was just looking at a dropdown fiddle online **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/6s8zyjwm/4/)** , there is the below line in the dropdown, like so:

```
 $(this).closest('.menu')[s.indexOf(g) !== -1 ? 'show' : 'hide']();
```

now i do understand ternary operators , and also i understand that

```
 $(this).closest('.menu')[0];
```

is a syntax often used to derive the 1st element , but i am not quite understanding the above syntax , how does the line get executed , or is it just:

```
 $(this).closest('.menu').hide();
```

depending on the result of the ternary operator ?

Comment: @PranavCBalan i am not understanding what you're trying to say !

Comment: @PranavCBalan yes that true they are jQuery methods !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its very simple. 
In JS you can access object members not only with **object.field_name** but also with **object['field_name']**

So your line of code can be translated as :

```
if(s.indexOf(g) !== -1) {
   // $(this).closest('.menu').show()
   $(this).closest('.menu')['show']() 
} else {
   // $(this).closest('.menu').hide()
   $(this).closest('.menu')['hide']() 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what .closest() does is, it traverse through the DOM element and matches for the match given in the context. Below is the actual syntax of closest

```
.closest( selector [, context ] )
```

So, what ever condition you will provide in context it will matches it and will return the element. In your case,

```
$(this).closest('.menu')[s.indexOf(g) !== -1 ? 'show' : 'hide']();
```

The closest is traversing through all the DOM elements of '.menu' and matching the DOM element with the alphabet entered in search box. If any of the DOM element in menu contains that alphabet then it will set its property to show() else will hide() it.